# How to force inheritors to run certain code before their own implamentation

Tags: c#, oop

I have a class which contains **static object**: `obj` and an **abstract method**: `AbsFoo();` 
The inheritor, needs to implements `AbsFoo`, but I would like to also force a **lock** over `obj`, before the implementation and, of course, release lock after the implementation.

How can I achieve that?

Comment: There's no way to do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only way to do this is to run the code in your base class.

You would create a `public` method that is called by the user. This method executes the code that always needs to be executed and then calls a protected method which performs the actual work and is overriden in the derived class:

```
public class Foo
{
    private readonly object _syncRoot = new object();

    public void AbsFoo()
    {
        // You can do more here, like some logging
        lock(_syncRoot)
        {
            AbsInternal();
        }
    }

    protected abstract void AbsInternal();
}

public class Bar : Foo
{
    protected override void AbsInternal()
    {
        // do work.
        // Note: No call to base.AbsInternal(); or base.AbsFoo(); here
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to use the template method pattern:

```
public void AbsFoo(){
   lock(obj){
      doActualWork();
   }
}

protected abstract void DoActualWork();
```

In short, you don't let implementors override AbsFoo, but rather a method which is delegated to, after your initialization code (in this case, locking).

Comment: You've been faster :) I'd go the same way.

Comment: But in this case implementer can call directly to DoActualWork() he might not even know about the existents of "AbsFoo()"

Comment: @choppy: The implementor doesn't have to call anything. Please see [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14997187/572644) for a more complete example.

Comment: @Daniel Hilgarth: What I meant is that after the implementer implements the  DoActualWork() abstract method, whenever he want to use that method (or anybody else for that meter), he will probably use instance.DoActualWork() and not base.AbsFoo(), do I miss something?

Comment: @choppy: "Anyone else" can't use it, because it is protected. And the class itself: Well, yes, you are right about that. All answers here - including mine - are looking at it from the point of an external consumer. Is this actually a scenario for you, that the method needs to be called from within the derived class?

Comment: @Daniel Hilgarth: You're right, the implementer shouldn't be the one how use the implementation!
Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

I think you should extend your design:

Prepare protected abstract method: AbsFooImpl() and AbsFoo() in your base class, which would look  like:

```
object AbsFoo()
{
    lock(obj)
    {
        AbsFooImpl();
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

**this is how to do it:**

```
public class Foo
{
    private readonly object _syncObj = new object();
    public void AbsFoo()
    {
       lock(syncObj )
       {
          doActualWork();
       }
    }

    protected abstract void doActualWork();
}

public class Bar : Foo
{
    protected override void doActualWork()
    {
        // do work.

    }
}
```

**Don't forget to use sealed !!!**

Comment: -1: `sealed` on a non-overriding method is not only useless but simply illegal: "cannot be sealed because it is not an override"

Comment: You don't want to make `AbsFoo` `virtual` either, because that would allow derived classes to circumvent the whole thing. And why would you seal `doActualWork`?